# Need help implementing a visualizer for merge sort with pygame

Tags: python, sorting, pygame

I am currently building a sorting visualizer using pygame, and I have been able to do bubble and selection sorts so far. What I am currently doing is drawing a frame of the array each time a change is made, which works for the bubble and selection sorts. But for merge sort, there are arrays always being split up and merged back, so I can't draw the array every frame because only a part of the array will show up each frame. I am currently stuck on how to implement the visualizer on merge sort, down bellow i will put an example of what works for the bubble sort, and what i currently have for merge sort.

```
# Bubble sort
def bubble_sort_visual(array, window, delay):
for i in range(len(array)):
    for j in range(0, len(array)-i-1):
        if array[j] > array[j + 1]:
            temp = array[j]
            array[j] = array[j + 1]
            array[j + 1] = temp
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, (15 + 15*j, 0, 10, temp))
            pygame.display.update()

        # This block of code is what I use to show the array on screen each frame
        window.fill(GREEN)
        array_bars(heights, screen, WHITE) # drawing the array each frame
        pygame.time.delay(delay)
        pygame.display.update()


 # Merge sort
 def merge_sort_visual(array, window, delay):
 if len(array) > 1:
    mid = len(array) // 2
    left_array = array[:mid]
    right_array = array[mid:]

    merge_sort_visual(left_array, screen, 8)
    merge_sort_visual(right_array, screen, 8)

    left_index = 0
    right_index = 0
    sort_index = 0

    while left_index < len(left_array) and right_index < len(right_array):
        if left_array[left_index] <= right_array[right_index]:
            array[sort_index] = left_array[left_index]
            left_index += 1

        else:
            array[sort_index] = right_array[right_index]
            right_index += 1

        sort_index += 1

    while left_index < len(left_array):
        array[sort_index] = left_array[left_index]
        left_index += 1
        sort_index += 1

    while right_index < len(right_array):
        array[sort_index] = right_array[right_index]
        right_index += 1
        sort_index += 1
```

As seen above, I am not sure where to put the block of code that i put in the bubble sort in the merge sort, i tried for a bit but each time i get the wrong result. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You could have an array of arrays that contains all the split arrays. Then have a scope-down method that displays it, and instead of displaying it in every sort, just call thst method from it.

Answer (score 1):

With the bubble, you're only dealing with a single array. With the merge sort, you're dealing with recursion and several layers of arrays. Updating the main array is a challenge since each layer of recursion only sees part of the full array.

The solution is to pass the partial array location to the child process so the child knows which part of the full array to update.

Here's the updated code to illustrate the idea:

```
 # Merge sort
 def merge_sort_visual(start, array, window, delay):  # pass the starting postion of this array within the full array (first call is 0)
 if len(array) > 1:
        mid = len(array) // 2
        left_array = array[:mid]
        right_array = array[mid:]

        # This block of code is what I use to show the array on screen each frame
        window.fill(GREEN) 
        # for this method, you will need to create a temporary copy of the full array to display on the screen 
        array_bars(start, array, heights, screen, WHITE) # update part of the full array on screen (start location and array length)
        pygame.time.delay(delay)
        pygame.display.update()

        merge_sort_visual(start, left_array, screen, 8)  # pass location within full array
        merge_sort_visual(start+mid, right_array, screen, 8)  # pass location within full array
```